# C# Azure Devops API Git: How to push files using the C# API

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops

So I've managed to get basic files being pushed with the API following the provided sample code.

I do this by reading the files line by line and converting them to a string, and sending them as Raw Text in the GitCommitRef as the example did. However, I'm unsure how to push more complex files that can't be easily read and converted to a string, such as DLLs.

Is there a way to push files such as these using C#?

Below is the code I use to create the commit:

```
        GitCommitRef commit = new GitCommitRef()
        {
            Comment = "Add a sample file",
            Changes = new GitChange[]
            {
                new GitChange()
                {
                    ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Add,
                    Item = new GitItem() {Path = "/TESTFOLDER/" + fileName, GitObjectType = GitObjectType.Blob, IsFolder = false },
                    NewContent = new ItemContent()
                    {
                        Content = Utilities.ReadFile(fileNamePath),
                        ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText
                    }

                }
             }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dlls and other more complex files that cannot be read into a string can be pushed by reading the file into an array of bytes, converting that array into a base64 string, and pushing that string with content type of EncodedBase64.

**Push the base 64 string**

```
                new GitChange()
                {
                    ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Add,
                    Item = new GitItem() {Path = "/TESTFOLDER/" + fileName2, GitObjectType = GitObjectType.Blob, IsFolder = false },
                    NewContent = new ItemContent()
                    {
                        Content = Utilities.ReadFileAsBytes(fileNamePath2).ToString(),
                        ContentType = ItemContentType.Base64Encoded
                    }

                }
```

**Get the string as Base 64**

```
        using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        {
            byte[] arr = new byte[stream.Length];
            int numBytesToRead = (int)stream.Length;
            while (numBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                int n = stream.Read(arr, 0, (int)stream.Length);

                if (n == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                numBytesToRead -= n;
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, you could mark it as an answer, In this case, others could directly find the useful solution. Thanks.